# How to load a apllication to the memory using shell scripting?

Tags: software-recommendation, scripts

How to load a apllication to the specified memory address using shell scripting concept.(sh/bash)

Comment: This cannot be performed by the shell.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the way modern operating systems re-map all the memory addresses via a Virtual Memory scheme, there is no way of knowing what the true address will be at any given time. Also, due to the protective measures imposed by modern OSs, you do not have direct access to hardware resources from a user-mode application.

Sources:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/announce.html?t=1293392
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory

Comment: Is it possible load application to any memory address which is free at that time?

Comment: @Sujatha Not in Ubuntu. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection.